# study real-world process with an artificial model

Tags: modeling, model, unbalanced-classes

I'm building a predictor for a classification problem. Some of the features are categorical, some are continuous, some are sparse, some are not. Unfortunately, the classes are very imbalanced, with one being over 99% of all the examples.

I suppose that there are some features that influence the response, while some are irrelevant. I've tried several approaches to feature selection and different classifiers.

Now I want to understand these relations deeper. Among other things I want to see how the dataset size changes the quality of the predictors I have, I want to compare different indicators for the different approaches and "play around" with different properties of the system.
So, I want to build a simulation that would reflect the system I'm studying (or actually any similar system). I'll start with some categorical variables: let's say we have `c1`, `c2` and `c3` as (binary) features, and I say that the probability that an example with `c1` belongs to class `A` is `0.01`, for class `c2` - `0.02`, and for class `c3` - `0.0005`. Then I generate data based on this probabilities, and apply my classifiers to this data. If an example has both `c1` and `c2`, I generate class `A` with probability of `(0.01 + 0.02) / 2 = 0.015`.
I hope this will give me a deeper understanding on the relations between different indicators and dataset size. I'll also see how feature selection performs.

Does this approach make sense? Or do I lose a huge amount of information when I make the assumptions above? I don't work with real data, I work with the model that represents my understanding of how the real world process runs. I mean, if I'm able to *model* the process this way, I should be able to build *ideal* classifier.